# sfdx force:source:deploy no results found

Tags: jenkins, salesforce

I hope someone can help us with this issue.

I have Jenkins set up on a Linux machine. I used JWT authentication to connect to Salesforce (Testing on Sandbox). Also, I'm using this tool (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-git-delta)to generate distructiveChanges.xml and package.xml files.

When I use the files generated by the nodeJS tool on my personal computer in Visual Studio Code and run the command sfdx:source:deploy, it works perfectly.

In Jenkins we get this message all the time

**+ sfdx force:source:deploy -u QA --verbose -x package/package.xml**

**Using specified username**

**=== Deployed Source**

**No results found**

If you need any more info, let me know below in the comments section and I will provide them ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Anyone can help please?

Comment: Is Jenkins definitely executing the delta package.xml generator across the same Git revision range as you are locally?

Comment: @DavidReed, yes it is, i checked the content of the package.xml file, it contains the list of changed files.